# How to correctly use g_gstring_append like function?

Tags: c, glib

everyone!
I'm using glib-2.0, GString struct.

Could g_string_append like function returns NULL?
How to check malloc errors?

Can I use it that?

```
GString *str = g_string_new("Hello, ");
g_string_append(str, "world!!!\n");

fprintf(stdout, "%s", str->str);

g_string_free(str);
```

or I should use something like that?

```
GString *str = g_string_new("Hello");
if (str == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "GString new error\n");    
    exit(1);
}

str = g_string_append(str, "world!!!\n\0");

if (str == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "GString append error\n");

    //Should I free str here?

    exit(1);
}

fprintf(stdout, "%s", str->str);
```

Comment: There is no use checking the return (which is downright poor design on glib's part). Glib presumes a valid return or the failure will be handled elsewhere [g_string_new](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/ctor.String.new.html)

Comment: The `GString` is returned so that multiple operations on it may be easily chained.

Answer (score 3):

If a `g_malloc` call fails then GLib will call [`g_error`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.error.html), which is always fatal so there is no need to check the return value.  `g_malloc` can actually return `NULL`, but only if you request an allocation of 0 bytes.  `g_realloc` basically behaves the same way, as do other allocation functions in GLib.

This behavior also makes its way up to functions like `g_string_append`, which uses `g_realloc` and therefore cannot fail.

Just to preempt the discussion which, in my experience, pretty much invariably follows this realization:

There has long been a debate about whether what GLib does here is a good thing or not.  The primary benefit is that it makes code a lot easier to write.  The primary drawback is that there is no way to gracefully handle an allocation failure; your application just dies.

That's not really as big a deal as some people make it out to be for several reasons, including that most operating systems [overcommit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment) anyways, most people aren't very good about checking the return value and it's much better to die immediately than to risk something much worse like silent data corruption.  It's definitely a problem for some people, such as safety-critical applications, bare-metal embedded programming, etc., but frankly GLib isn't intended for those use cases anyways.

Either way, it is what it is.  The decision was made 20+ years ago, and it's not going to change.  If that means GLib isn't acceptable for your use case then I am sorry, but you are going to have to use something else.  Probably something without any dynamic allocation whatsoever since standards for safety-critical code, like MISRA, don't allow it anyways.